# OpengL ES / Angle : rendering to single channel float texture

Tags: floating-point, shader, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture

I am trying to use shaders to do simple operations on large matrices/images. I wrote some code running with regular OpenGL by rendering to single channel float textures in frame buffer objects, which works fine.

I would now need to have it run on different platforms (UWP + Angle, Android,...) so I'm trying to port the code to OpenGL ES 2.0 ; I can make it work with regular RGBA images, but doesn't with float images.

What works (output buffer 'data_out' contains result of the render)

```
format = GL_RGBA;
type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
internal_format = GL_RGBA;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format,
    width,
    height,
    0, format, type,
    Data

(...)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (2) * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data_out);
```

What doesn't work :

```
format = GL_RED_EXT;
type = GL_FLOAT;
internal_format = GL_RED_EXT;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internal_format,
    width,
    height,
    0, format, type,
    Data);
(...)
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_FLOAT, data_out);
```

What I expect in data_out :

```
27.0000000  float
22.7840576  float
11.4528332  float
-3.45501971 float
-17.2838974 float
-25.7151508 float
-26.1157665 float
(...)
```

What I get :

```
-25.7161427 float
-25.7161427 float
-25.7161427 float
-25.7161427 float
-25.7161427 float
-17.2863979 float
-17.2863979 float
(...)
```

I could not find many similar issues online, except for the following discussion :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webgl-dev-list/ms21hnWk0tg
, which seems to conclude "it can't be done", but was written back in 2012.

So is there really no way of rendering to a single channel float texture with OpenGL ES 2.0 ? Because that would be a major issue to my project.

Update -
So I tried the float to/from RGBA encoding mentioned in the comment below.

```
inline float4 EncodeFloatRGBA( float v ) {
float4 enc = float4(1.0, 255.0, 65025.0, 160581375.0) * v;
enc = frac(enc);
enc -= enc.yzww * float4(1.0/255.0,1.0/255.0,1.0/255.0,0.0);
return enc;
}
inline float DecodeFloatRGBA( float4 rgba ) {
return dot( rgba, float4(1.0, 1/255.0, 1/65025.0, 1/160581375.0) );
}
void main()
{
float raw_value = DecodeFloatRGBA(texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV ));
gl_FragColor = EncodeFloatRGBA(raw_value);
}
```

Pushing a texture filled with an arbitrary value (5.23) and retrieving the display with glReadPixels, I get only 3 bytes out of 4, alpha being stuck to 0

input value (byte per byte)

```
[0] 41 ')'  unsigned char
[1] 92 '\\' unsigned char
[2] 167 '§' unsigned char
[3] 64 '@'  unsigned char
```

output value (byte per byte)

```
[0] 41 ')'  unsigned char
[1] 92 '\\' unsigned char
[2] 167 '§' unsigned char
[3] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
```

Answer (score 0):

For floating point format support you need the extension: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_texture_float.txt

For single channel render formats you need the extension: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt

It's not an unusual approach to encode a floating point number across multiple channels of an 8888 or 4444 render target. There's an example and several links here: http://aras-p.info/blog/2009/07/30/encoding-floats-to-rgba-the-final/

Comment: Thanks. I checked the extensions with the following command : const `GLubyte* msg = glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);` , and I do see GL_OES_texture_float and GL_EXT_texture_rg on the list. The way I understand it, I can handle such textures, but not render to them.   I will look into encoding/decoding float to RGBA format, although I suppose it will hit the performance.

Comment: You are right. There is https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_color_buffer_half_float.txt which adds half floats for GLES 2 but no full float equivalent that I can find except https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_color_buffer_float.txt which requires GLES 3.

Comment: So I implemented the encoding/decoding functions mentioned above ( http://aras-p.info/blog/2009/07/30/encoding-floats-to-rgba-the-final/ ) in a simple pass-through test, and the result is different than the source, because the alpha channel is set to zero.  Looking further, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893302/decode-rgb-value-to-single-float-without-bit-shift-in-glsl with the comment "Note that you can't store alpha too(in this way), since highp floats are 24-bit long, and not 32 as the ones normally used". So the first version of the code isn't supposed to work ?